# except, it returns the excepts but it continues to run, python

Tags: python, except

```
hours = input("Enter hours: ")

rate = input("Enter rate: ")

try:
    hours = float(hours)
    rate = float(rate)
except:
    print("Enter real numbers")

def computepay(hours, rate):
    if hours <= 40.0:
        pay = hours * rate
        return pay
    elif hours > 40:
        pay = 40 * rate
        exhrs = (hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate)
        totpay = pay + exhrs
        return totpay

print("Pay: %s" % computepay(hours, rate))
```

- [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhxbJ.png

Comment: what do you mean it continues to run?

Answer (score 1):

The `except` block is executed when an exception is raised by the code in the `try` block. There is no magic involved that would know that your user needs to re-enter those numbers, you'll have to provide the code for that yourself.

Also, you should always be specific with your exceptions. One possible way of doing this would be

```
while True:
    hours = input("Enter hours: ")
    rate = input("Enter rate: ")
    try:
        hours = float(hours)
        rate = float(rate)
        break              # end the while loop if no error occurred
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter real numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior. If you rise some exception then script will be terminated, in other case except will only print message. except doesn't terminate script.